# R: How to keep names while unnesting doubled nested tibble?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, names, unnest

at the moment I'm trying to figure out how to keep the names of an inner and other list nested within a tibble while unnesting.

The `.id` parameter of the `unnest` function is the closest I found, but it starts to number the values instead of using the given names.

here is a MWE with my idea of the final tibble:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df.1 <- tibble(
  x = list("Foo","Bar"),
  y = list(
    list(a = list(aa = 1, ab = 2), b = list(ba = 6, bb = 22)),
    list(c = list(ca = 561, cb = 35), d = list(da = 346, db = 17))
  )
)

df.2 <- unnest(df.1, .id = "name.outher")
df.3 <- unnest(df.2, .id = "name.inner")

# How do I get from this:
#
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
#  x  |                              y                                 |
#-----+----------------------------------------------------------------+
# Foo | list(a = list(aa = 1, ab = 2), b = list(ba = 6, bb = 22))      |
#-----+----------------------------------------------------------------+
# Bar | list(c = list(ca = 561, cb = 35), d = list(da = 346, db = 17)) |
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# to this:
#
#---------------------------------------
#  x  | name.outher | y   | name.inner |
#-----+-------------+-----+------------+
# Foo |      a      | 1   |     aa     |
#-----+-------------+-----+------------+
# Foo |      a      | 2   |     ab     |
#-----+-------------+-----+------------+
# Foo |      b      | 6   |     ba     |
#-----+-------------+-----+------------+
# Foo |      b      | 22  |     bb     |
#-----+-------------+-----+------------+
# Bar |      c      | 561 |     ca     |
#-----+-------------+-----+------------+
# Bar |      c      | 35  |     cb     |
#-----+-------------+-----+------------+
# Bar |      d      | 346 |     da     |
#-----+-------------+-----+------------+
# Bar |      d      | 17  |     db     |
#-------------------------------------
# 
# instead of this:
#
#---------------------------------------
#  x  | name.outher | y   | name.inner |
#-----+-------------+-----+------------+
# Foo |      1      | 1   |     1      |
#-----+-------------+-----+------------+
# Foo |      1      | 2   |     1      |
#-----+-------------+-----+------------+
# Foo |      1      | 6   |     2      |
#-----+-------------+-----+------------+
# Foo |      1      | 22  |     2      |
#-----+-------------+-----+------------+
# Bar |      2      | 561 |     3      |
#-----+-------------+-----+------------+
# Bar |      2      | 35  |     3      |
#-----+-------------+-----+------------+
# Bar |      2      | 346 |     4      |
#-----+-------------+-----+------------+
# Bar |      2      | 17  |     4      |
#---------------------------------------
```

Do you have any idea how i can preserve the names while unnesting this data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `melt`

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
df.1 %>% 
   .$y %>% 
   melt %>%
   select(x = L1, name.outher = L2, y = value, name.inner = L3)
#  x name.outher   y name.inner
#1 1           a   1         aa
#2 1           a   2         ab
#3 1           b   6         ba
#4 1           b  22         bb
#5 2           c 561         ca
#6 2           c  35         cb
#7 2           d 346         da
#8 2           d  17         db
```

---

Or use `map` and `as_tibble`

```
library(tidyverse)
df.1 %>%
   pull(y) %>% 
   map_df(~ as_tibble(.x) %>%
                map_df(~as_tibble(.x) %>%
                    gather(name.inner, y), .id = 'name.outer'),
     .id = 'x')
# A tibble: 8 x 4
#  x     name.outer name.inner     y
#  <chr> <chr>      <chr>      <dbl>
#1 1     a          aa             1
#2 1     a          ab             2
#3 1     b          ba             6
#4 1     b          bb            22
#5 2     c          ca           561
#6 2     c          cb            35
#7 2     d          da           346
#8 2     d          db            17
```

Comment: This is pretty close to it (thank you), but the first column (marked "x") is missing, is it possible to add it?

Comment: @Someone2  Sorry, I removed that column in `select`.  Fixed

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but I found a problem: I edited my MWE a little so "x" goes from 3 to 4 and now the "x" column does not work any longer. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @Someone2 or, `df.1 %>% 
    .$y %>% 
    melt %>%
    mutate(L1 = df.1$x[L1]) %>%
    select(x = L1, name.outher = L2, y = value, name.inner = L3)`

Comment: Sorry, my example was bad, in reality I use strings as "x", I fixed it now. @Andre Elrico your last example works fine for chars, thank you.

Comment: you changed x to be a list, => `df.1 %>% .$y %>% melt %>% select(name.outher = L2, y = value, name.inner = L3) %>% {cbind(x = rep(unlist(df.1$x), each = nrow(.)/nrow(df.1)), . )}`

Comment: I like the mutate one more anyways. Please note, with the mutate one your `x` will be a list on elements. using `... %>%
    mutate(L1 = unlist(df.1$x[L1])) %>% ...` would omit that.